# Book that ends with the lines "Fall in love, it makes you brave. Ah, yes, very brave."

Tags: identification-request

Looking for what is probably a young adult book, pre-80's, possibly fantasy, that I read long ago which ends with these 2 lines, the 2nd line being its own paragraph:

> "Fall in love, it makes you brave.
>   Ah, yes, very brave."

This harks back to advice a that the main character was given earlier in the book.

Comment: Do you have any more information? What gender was the main character? Who gave the advice? What makes you think it was fantasy? WEhat was that earlier advice?

Answer (score 10):

***The Courtship of Eddie's Father*, by Mark Toby**.

First, I found this snippet from a story in the magazine "Good Housekeeping", volume 153, page 187, from 1961. The whole thing is not available online, but searching through Google Books gave me this:

> “You bet! ! !” We sat there for a minute, grinning at each other. Then I picked up the telephone. I dialed Elizabeth's number. Ed. die watched me with shining eyes. Rule eight, remember? Fall in love; it makes you brave. Ah, yes. Very brave. e.

I'm assuming the "e." means end in that snippet.

[image: screenshot of Google Books result]

You can search through random snippets of the magazine on [Google Books](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=sjlbP25PnYQC&dq=%22love%22+%22makes+you+brave%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=shining+eyes), but I couldn't get the exact text to show up - the closest I got was right above it:

[image]

You can also see that there are results for the words "very brave" on page 187 at [Hathitrust](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt/search?q1=very+brave&id=uc1.31158013368864&view=1up&seq=13).

I found it by doing a Google Books search for `"love" "makes you brave"`, and it was about the tenth result. Then I just had to go searching for confirmation.

From what I see on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007I1RC9G), the issue contains an entire novel (as seen on the cover).

[image: cover of the issue]

I searched through the book for "novel" on Google Books, which led to me finding the title, *The Courtship of Eddie's Father*:

[image: snippet that says the title]

The reviews on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/7743169#other_reviews) indicate that this is not a fantasy novel, however. It also had a [sitcom based off of the novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Courtship_of_Eddie%27s_Father), which was not fantasy.

Going to the [Google Books page](https://books.google.co.il/books?redir_esc=y&id=WTxHAAAAYAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=very+brave) for the book directly, we can see that it ends on the "fall in love" lines, on their own paragraph:

[image: screenshot of ending, transcript below]

> [Ed]die watched me with shining eyes.
>   Rule eight, remember? Fall in love; it makes you brave.
>   Ah, yes. Very brave.
>   THE END

Comment: There's a [copy available for loan](https://archive.org/details/courtshipofeddie00toby) at the Internet Archive.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! That's right, I read this novel several times. It's lovely. I also LOVED the series when I was a kid. That's how I found the book. Funny what sticks in your head.
Now I have a better idea how to search for other lines that pop into my head!